# Why is a UTF-8 string not equal to the equivalent ASCII-8BIT string in Ruby 2.0?

Tags: ruby, string, encoding, utf-8, ruby-2.0

I am using Ruby 2.3:

I have the following string: `"\xFF\xFE"`

I do a `File.binread()` on a file containing it, so the encoding of this string is `ASCII-8BIT`. However, in my code, i check to see whether this string was indeed read by comparing it to the literal string `"\xFF\xFE"` (which has encoding `UTF-8` as all Ruby strings have by default).

However, the comparison returns `false`, even though both strings contain the same bytes - it just happens that one is with encoding `ASCII-8BIT` and the other is `UTF-8`

I have two questions: (1) why does it return `false` ? and (2) what is the best way to go about achieving what i want? I just want to check whether the string I read matches `"\xFF\xFE"`

Comment: If you just want to read a file with a Unicode BOM, you can pass an [encoding](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/IO.html#method-c-new-label-IO+Encoding) of `'BOM|UTF-8'` and let Ruby handle it automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> (1) why does it return `false`?

When comparing strings, they either have to be in the same encoding or their characters must be encodable in US-ASCII.

Comparison works as expected if the string only contains byte values 0 to 127: (`0b0xxxxxxx`)

```
a = 'E'.encode('ISO8859-1')  #=> "E"
b = 'E'.encode('ISO8859-15') #=> "E"

a.bytes #=> [69]
b.bytes #=> [69]
a == b  #=> true
```

And fails if it contains any byte values 128 to 255: (`0b1xxxxxxx`)

```
a = 'É'.encode('ISO8859-1')  #=> "\xC9"
b = 'É'.encode('ISO8859-15') #=> "\xC9"

a.bytes #=> [201]
b.bytes #=> [201]
a == b  #=> false
```

Your string can't be represented in US-ASCII, because both its bytes are outside its range:

```
"\xFF\xFE".bytes #=> [255, 254]
```

Attempting to convert it doesn't produce any meaningful result:

```
"\xFF\xFE".encode('US-ASCII', 'ASCII-8BIT', :undef => :replace)
#=> "??"
```

The string will therefore return `false` when being compared to a string in another encoding, regardless of its content.

> (2) what is the best way to go about achieving what i want?

You could compare your string to a string with the same encoding. `binread` returns a string in `ASCII-8BIT` encoding, so you could use [`b`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/String.html#method-i-b) to create a compatible one:

```
IO.binread('your_file', 2) == "\xFF\xFE".b
```

or you could compare its [`bytes`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/String.html#method-i-bytes):

```
IO.binread('your_file', 2).bytes == [0xFF, 0xFE]
```

Comment: But it's 8 bit ascii and the characters 255 and 254 are defined. So what's up with that? `"\xFF\xFE".encode('ASCII-8BIT')` works just fine. Is it because it's not valid UTF-8 ?

Comment: There is no such thing as "8 bit ascii". ASCII is, has always been, and will always be 7 bit.

Comment: @banister you are confusing `'ASCII-8BIT'` with `'US-ASCII'` and my answer wasn't very precise in that regard either. I've updated it accordingly.

Comment: @JörgWMittag ok then "extended ascii is 8 bit" is that ok? :) From wikipedia, "The extended ASCII character set uses 8 bits"

Comment: @horseyguy Wikipedia says that? "extended ASCII" is an umbrella term referring to any encoding built on top of ASCII. Even UTF-8 is extended ASCII.

Comment: @Stefan i think it's a misnomer now (and possibly then too), but in early DOS days 'extended ascii' was generally used to refer to only one 8-bit character set possibly due to built-in dos support. I agree 'extended ascii' doesn't appear to make sense now though, http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/letter-u-with-umlaut-diaeresis-lowercase-u-umlaut-ascii-code-129.html

Comment: @horseyguy that looks like [code page 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850). I always preferred [code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) because of the superior box drawing capabilities :-)